# Server Error upon joining many rooms in a short period of time

Tags: socket.io, rate-limiting, server-error, goinstant

My application joins about 50 rooms for one user on one connection all at once. After a couple rooms successfully join I start to get a server error return on some of the rooms.

There error is always the same, here it is:

```
Error: Server Error
    at Object.i.build (https://cdn.goinstant.net/v1/platform.min.js:4:7501)
    at Connection._onResponse (https://cdn.goinstant.net/v1/platform.min.js:7:25694)
    at Connection._onMessage (https://cdn.goinstant.net/v1/platform.min.js:7:28812)
    at Connection._onMessage (https://cdn.goinstant.net/v1/platform.min.js:3:4965)
    at r.e (https://cdn.goinstant.net/v1/platform.min.js:1:4595)
    at r.emit (https://cdn.goinstant.net/v1/platform.min.js:2:6668)
    at r.e (https://cdn.goinstant.net/v1/platform.min.js:1:4595)
    at r.emit (https://cdn.goinstant.net/v1/platform.min.js:3:7482)
    at r.onPacket (https://cdn.goinstant.net/v1/platform.min.js:3:14652)
    at r.<anonymous> (https://cdn.goinstant.net/v1/platform.min.js:3:12614)
```

It's not isolated to any particular rooms, sometimes half of them pass, sometimes nearly all pass, but there are almost always a couple that break.

What I have found is if it's less than 10 rooms it won't break.

Is there any rate limiting on joining rooms that could be causing this? I'd rather not put a delay between each room join but I can if I need to.

**Update:** It definitely has to do with how fast I'm connecting to the rooms. Spacing them out by 1s each makes it work every time. I need to connect faster though, is there a fix for this?

Even a 100ms deplay seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a case of rate-limiting or anything along those lines. It's a bug and we are working to fix it as soon as we can. We'll update you here once we have a solution deployed. If you'd like for us to email you a notification directly, drop us a message via our contact form (https://goinstant.com/contact). Just make reference to this issue and I'll make sure a note is added to email you directly as soon as the fix goes live.

Sorry for any inconvenience this may be causing you.

Regards,

Thomas

Developer, GoInstant

Comment: No problem, the workaround we have in place is working fine for now. Thanks for the quick reply!